# SSLError "UKNOWN_PROTOCOL" imaplib Python

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, imaplib, sslerrorhandler

I am trying to connect to an email server with my own credentials in Python. The script works great until the exception "SSLError" shows up. Sometimes it occurs as soon as starting up the script or after running the script for a few hours. I created an exception for it, but that does not work.As long as the SSLError exception occurs, the script will not connect.. Someone please help as I am not a professional:

```
IMAP4_SSL_PORT = 993

while True:

    now = datetime.now()
    msrver = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host = 'myemailserver.com',port = IMAP4_SSL_PORT)

    unm = 'usernamehere'
    pwd = 'passwordhere'
    msrver.login(unm,pwd)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ereyes\Desktop\TestScripts\Database Automation.py", line    16, in <module>
msrver = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host = 'myemailserver.com',port =   IMAP4_SSL_PORT)
File "C:\Python27\lib\imaplib.py", line 1166, in __init__
IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
File "C:\Python27\lib\imaplib.py", line 173, in __init__
self.open(host, port)
File "C:\Python27\lib\imaplib.py", line 1178, in open
self.sslobj = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *the script never establishes a connection to the server until after a few hours which is way too long to wait for* - I don't understand. Does the code for connecting to the server works, works not or fails to work sometimes? Why do you need to wait hours, couldn't you just extract the code for connecting and try this outside the script?

Comment: As long as the SSLError exception occurs, the script will not connect. I should re-word what I said before, apologies. In that case I wait a while before running the script again for a connection to occur.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly: the imap connect and TLS handshake works repeatedly several times until it suddenly stops working with `unknown protocol`. After that it will fail always with this error until you restart the script?

Comment: Correct! That is how I should have said it.

Comment: Then this is a very unusual behavior, especially the part that it never succeeds until restart but succeeds immediately after restart. I think you would need to make a minimal version of the program which allows others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with SSL certificates?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not related to certificates. Unknown protocol happens if the other party does not properly speak TLS or no TLS at all. For example this could happen if you connect with SSL directly to port 143(imap) instead of 993(imaps), since on port 143 TLS have to be initiated with STARTTLS command first and on port 993 there is TLS from start.

Comment: I see. I will continue to work on this. Thank you very much for your insight, it is very appreciated!